# How do I add this JavaScript code to Zapier, to issue a 3rd party gift?

Tags: javascript, zapier

My eCommerce website needs to run JavaScript code so a 3rd party can send the customer a gift. The JavaScript code worked on the Thank You page, but I need to have a few-day delay before the script runs, so I'm trying to do this with Zapier instead.  But Zapier is giving the following error when the same code is used there:

**The run javascript could not be sent to Code by Zapier. SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

Zapier Support could not help, and I couldn't find the solution in Zapier's documentation.

Can someone please help modify the short code below, so that it can be run by Zapier?

```js
<script src="https://members.thirdparty.com/jsapi/fbDE_Voucher.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var fdDE_detail = {
"fbDE_sender":'12345-67890',
"fbDE_fullname":"'"+inputData.CustName+"'",
"fbDE_email":"'"+inputData.CustEmail+"'",
"fbDE_amount":inputData.VoucherValue,
"fbDE_business":54321,
"fbDE_message":'Thank you for your purchase!'
}
fbDEVoucher(fdDE_detail);
}
</script>
```

The variables CustName, CustEmail, and VoucherValue are from prior Zapier steps.  The first 2 need to be within single quotes, and the third is an integer (not requiring quotes).  Please see image below:

[JavaScript code for Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQQ4o.png)

**Does anyone know how to fix the above error (in bold) so this code runs?**

Appreciate your help!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Zapier's code runs in `Node.js`, which is a different environment than the browser-based JS your code was running in before.

First off, `<script>` tags aren't available, since that's HTML. Whatever code comes in through `fbDE_Voucher.min.js` will need to be loaded separately. If it's not too long, you can paste it into the code window (but there's a better solution, see below).

There's also no `window` global, but you don't need it anyway. So to get this close to working, it would be something like:

```js
// doesn't work, fbDEVoucher is undefined
fbDEVoucher({
  fbDE_sender: "12345-67890",
  fbDE_fullname: inputData.CustName, // doesn't need to be re-wrapped in a string
  fbDE_email: inputData.CustEmail,
  fbDE_amount: inputData.VoucherValue,
  fbDE_business: 54321,
  fbDE_message: "Thank you for your purchase!",
});
```

That's all you would need, assuming your function is already defined.

---

The best option for you here is to create a custom Zapier integration. This gives you a more full-featured JS environment than a `Code by Zapier` step, plus dramatically more control. You can include the aforementioned file and call the function as needed. There's docs about that here: https://platform.zapier.com/